# MissingPluginException - Permission issue with HttpClient

Tags: flutter

I am getting this issue, please help me to sort out [this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LEjC.png)

```
I/flutter (24380): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method checkPermissionStatus on channel flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/methods)
E/flutter (24380): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI null&lon=null&appid=43972b8f9f08a959aaf0d6fcf16f80f4&units=metric
E/flutter (24380): #0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2425:9)
E/flutter (24380): #1      _HttpClient.openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2341:7)
E/flutter (24380): #2      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:31:37)
E/flutter (24380): #3      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:91:38)
E/flutter (24380): #4      BaseClient.get (package:http/src/base_client.dart:27:7)
E/flutter (24380): #5      get.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:46:36)
E/flutter (24380): #6      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:20)
E/flutter (24380): #7      get (package:http/http.dart:46:5)
E/flutter (24380): #8      NetworkHelper.getData (package:clima/services/networking.dart:13:31)
E/flutter (24380): #9      WeatherModel.getLocationWeather (package:clima/services/weather.dart:19:43)
E/flutter (24380): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24380): #10     _LoadingScreenState.getLocationData (package:clima/screens/loading_screen.dart:33:22)
E/flutter (24380): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24380):
```

Comment: Stop your app, run `flutter pub get` and run your app again.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here.

- The MissingPluginException is an information : you're not checking the permissions and I guess the Location class is requiring this check. Without it, you won't be able to retrieve the user's location.
- The object NetworkHelper you're creating is invalid since you didn't include the `openWeatherMapURL` var at the beginning of your query (and you're also missing the "lat" parameter)